# How to compile rarcrack-0.2 on mac osx 10.6.5?

Tags: xcode, macos

Hi how do I compile rarcrack-0.2 on mac osx 10.6.5 available here, http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/. When I compile using make it throws this error:

```
> V3628TU:rarcrack-0.2 admin$ make
> gcc -pthread rarcrack.c `xml2-config --libs --cflags` -O2 -o rarcrack
> rarcrack.c: In function ‘init’:
> rarcrack.c:283: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char
> (*)[300]’
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error

Comment: Just to clarify, a warning means it still compiles.

Comment: But when run it, it throws this: sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The format argument should remain %s. Change "&test" to just "test".

Comment: I did that and got a little further.

make
`gcc -pthread rarcrack.c xml2-config --libs --cflags -O2 -o rarcrack
mymac:rarcrack-0.2 me$ sudo su
Password:
sh-3.2# make install
install -s rarcrack /usr/bin
mkdir -p /usr/share/doc/rarcrack
chmod 755 /usr/share/doc/rarcrack
install -m 644 -t /usr/share/doc/rarcrack CHANGELOG LICENSE README README.html RELEASE_NOTES
install: illegal option -- t
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m make: *** [install] Error 64
sh-3.2# `